# Buttons are horizontally aligned

Tags: html, css

Check out the code

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  width: 28vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 7vw;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.login {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12vw;
}

.register {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>

<body class=background>
  <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
</body>

</html>
```

What this is doing is horizontally aligning the buttons. But I want the **Register** button to be below the **Login** button.
Is there anything that I'm missing.?

I tried **br** as well, but it's not working as well.
How can I make it work?

Comment: Do you mean you want the Register button directly underneath the Login button? You need to remove `float: right` and add `display: block` to the Register button

Comment: but then how will I make the buttons to appear on the right side.?

Comment: You need to wrap the buttons in a parent element (e.g: `div`) and float that.

Comment: thanks @vanita It worked

Answer (score 0):

```css
.layer { 
    margin: 10px 0 0 10px; 
    width:100%; 
    float: left;
}
.child { 
    float: both; 
    margin-left: 0px; 
    margin-top: 0px; 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
       <head>
          <title>HOME</title>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
       </head>
       <body>
          <div class="layer">
             <div class="child">1</div>
             <div class="child">2</div>
          </div>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `float:right` in you `.button` class. I removed it and added `display:block`. Study the behavior of `float` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position:relative;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 28vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 7vw;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.login {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}

.register {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 5vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>

<body class=background>
  <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemed like you wanted to align the buttons in the middle one below the other. **To keep it *responsive* and to achieve what you wanted i made a few small changes:**

Changed the button css -

1) `width` to `30%`

2) `min-width` to `150px`

3) `margin-right` to `35%` `//calculation : (100% - 30%)/2`

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: right;
  min-width: 150px;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 35%;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.login {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12vw;
}

.register {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 2vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>

<body class=background>
  <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the float from your button to the container div

```
<!doctype html>
  <html lang="en">
    <html>
      <style>
      body,
      html {
        margin: 0;
        height: 100%;
      }

      div{
      text-align:right;
      }

  .button {
    border: none;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 16px;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 28vw;
    border-radius: 50px;
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 7vw;
  }

  .button:hover {
    background-color: green;
  }

  </style>

  <head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
  </head>

  <body class=background>
  <div>
    <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  </div>
  <div>
    <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
  </div>
  </body>

  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display: block` to the button takes up the whole width of parent block, so following button will be placed in new line. It is possible to use `auto` for horizontal margins to center your buttons.

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  margin: 2vw auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 28vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

.login {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
}

.register {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>

<body class=background>
  <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.layer { 
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: table;
  margin-top: 34vh;
  /* you need to play a littl bit with the vh maybe something around 30-40vh*/
}

#child1, #child2 { 
float: both; 
margin-left: 0px; 
margin-top: 0px;  
}


.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 28vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>
<body>
<body class="background">
  <div class="layer">
  <div class="child">
    <button class="button child">LOGIN</button>
  </div>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div class="child">
    <button class="button child">REGISTER</button>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each button in a div

```css
body,
html {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.background {
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(../images/home-background.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.btn-container {
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  border: none;
  padding: 15px 25px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 16px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float: none;
  clear: both;
  width: 28vw;
  border-radius: 50px;
  position: relative;
  margin-right: 7vw;
}

.button:hover {
  background-color: green;
}

.login {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12vw;
}

.register {
  background-color: #DF6248;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 12vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>HOME</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/home.css">
</head>

<body class=background>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="button login">LOGIN</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-container">
    <button class="button register">REGISTER</button>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```